# addEventListener overwrites other event actions?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

Does `addEventListener` overwrite previously defined actions for a particular event? For example,

```
<input type="text" name="ele" id="eleID" onfocus="doSomeThing();"/>
```

Now if I add another action for the same event, will both both function get executed?

```
eleID.addEventListener('focus',doSomethingElse,false);
```

If `doSomethingElse()` overwrites `doSomeThing()`, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

No.

[From MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener):

> addEventListener is the way to register an event listener as specified in W3C DOM. Its benefits are as follows:
>
> - It allows adding more than a single handler for an event.

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/UhdT6/).

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not "overwrite" other handlers; that's why it's called "**add**EventListener".  All the handlers are invoked when an event happens.

Now, I will say that *mixing* the old-style "DOM 0" event handler attachment mechanism (the "on*event*" attributes) with event handlers added with "addEventListener()" is not a very good practice.